# Return multiple columns on single CASE DB2

Tags: db2

Is it possible to return multiple column on single CASE evaluation in DB2?
below query return single column.

```
select (case when 1=1 then 0 else 1 end) as col from table;
```

I need multiple column like

```
select (case when 1=1 then 0 as col, 1 as col1 else 2 as col1 , 3 as col2 end) from table;
select (case when 1=1 then 0,1 else 2, 3  end)col , col1 from table;
```

Is coalesce function is use full for above conditions? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible with a single CASE statement in Db2.

But you may use something like below.

```
select 
  coalesce(t1.c1, t2.c1, t3.c1) c1
, coalesce(t1.c2, t2.c2, t3.c2) c2
from 
(
  select tabschema, tabname, rownumber() over (partition by tabschema) rn_
  from syscat.tables
) b
left join table(values ('_SYSIBM_', b.tabname)) t1 (c1, c2) on b.tabschema='SYSIBM'
left join table(values ('_SYSCAT_', b.tabname)) t2 (c1, c2) on b.tabschema='SYSCAT'
cross join table(values (b.tabschema, b.tabname)) t3 (c1, c2)
where b.rn_=1;
```

The `sub-select` on `syscat.tables` is constructed to return only one table from each schema just to show the idea (your base table must be there instead of it). "Case condition" here is what you see in the `on` clause of each `join`. "Returned values" of this "Case expression" are inside the `values` clauses.

Comment: any other option.

Comment: Distinct `case` expression for each column or `union all` of the same `sub-select` statements - one for each combination of expressions. Exact such a statement may be constructed, when you provide some real-life example of the `case` condition instead of `1=1`.

Comment: BTW. What’s the problem with distinct `case` expression in your case?

Comment: "1=1" is just for example, it may be column of table.

Answer (score 0):

A CASE statement can be re-written as a UNION. Logically they are the same thing.
So, you could do this

```
select 0 as col, 1 as col1 from table where 1=1
UNION ALL
select 2 as col, 3 as col1 from table where NOT 1=1 OR 1=1 IS NULL
```